# Unable to get Javascript to use JSON/Flask response to both redirect to new page AND update its DOM

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building a chat app, not unlike Slack. I present the user with a page in which to enter the name of a channel on `channels.html`. The following Javascript successfully catches the entry, throws it to the appropriate Flask route, and receives a JSON response, which it processes by constructing a `<div>` stored in `contents`.

Desired behavior: I get an immediate redirect on form submission to `messages.html` and the DOM element `#channelList` changes. I've triple

I thought I could do this sequentially by turning the page with `windows.location.href` and changing the `.innerHTML` property of the desired element, but it is a no go,  and I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of null` in my console, in references to the line `document.querySelector('#channelList').innerHTML += contents;`. The element is very much there and spelled correctly. What gives?

**Javascript:**

```
(function() {

    var form = document.querySelector('#channelForm'),
        button = form.querySelector('input.btn-primary');

    if (!button) console.log('move your js below your html')

    console.log('binding listener to', button);

    button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log('process form data!');
      console.log("here");

      // initialize request
      const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      const channelName = document.querySelector('#channelName').value;

      request.open('POST', '/channels');

      request.onload = () => {

          // Extract JSON data from request
          const data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
          console.log(data);

          // Update the result div
          if (data.success == true) {

            let contents = ""; 

            for (let i = 0, j = data["channel"].length; i < j; i++) {

              contents += "<div>" + data["channel"][i] + "</div>";
              console.log(contents);

            }

            window.location.href = Flask.url_for("messages");
            document.querySelector('#channelList').innerHTML += contents;

          } else {

             console.log("error");
          }

      };

      // Add data to send with request
      const data = new FormData();
      data.append('channel', channelName);

      // Send request to Flask
      request.send(data);
      //return false;

    });

})()
```

**HTML for page where element exists, but console says they are null**

```
<div class="col-md-3 border border-danger rounded">
    <div class="row mt-2 justify-content-start">
        Header
    </div>
    <div class="row mt-2 justify-content-start" id="channelHeader">
        <a href="{{ url_for('channels') }}">Channels</a>
    </div>
    <div class="row mt-2 justify-content-start" id="channelList">
        Channels
    </div>
    &nbsp;
    <div class="row justify-content-start" id="dmsg">
        Direct Messages
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This specific error is caused by line #3:

```
 var form = document.querySelector('#channelForm'),
        button = form.querySelector('input.btn-primary');
```

From the code you provided, the id you mentioned (channelList) exists but it doesn't look like the element that comes before it, channelForm, exists. At least in what is shown here.

Comment: I edited for clarity. The problematic line is below that. Thanks for looking at the code though.

Comment: This line is still the cause. Because #channelForm does not exist, there is no input.btn-primary either. Here is a JSFiddle which demonstrates: https://jsfiddle.net/zcepj4r8/

Comment: Those exist on `channels.html`. They submit to JS which sends text to a Flask Route which responds with a JSON object. All of that works. What doesn't work is that after I am redirected to `messages.html` the DOM in `messages.html` is not updated.